# Find paragraphs by style in word 2010 using interop

Tags: c#, ms-word

Could someone point me in the right direction, or show me how to find paragraphs by their style name using word interop in c#.net.

Comment: This questions seems to be asking something similar:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865340/vsto-2007-how-do-i-determine-the-page-and-paragraph-number-of-a-range

Answer (score 1):

Try loop like this:

```
using WN = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
//...
        WN::Application WordApp;
        WordApp = new WN.Application();
//...        
    WN.Document WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(Filename); //open document

        List<string> SelectedParagraphs = new List<string>();
        for(int i=1;i<WordDoc.Paragraphs.Count;i++) //numeration of paragraphs starts from 1
        {
                string WordP = WordDoc.Paragraphs[i].Range.Text; // get paragraph text
                string WordS = ((WN.Style)WordDoc.Paragraphs[i].get_Style()).NameLocal; //get paragraph style name
                if (WordS=="Needed style")
                {
                    SelectedParagraphs.Add(WordP);
                }
        }
```