# How to find instances of text with a specific style applied in Word 2010

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

The objective is to build a list of text elements in a Word 2010 document, identified by having a specific style applied. This list is then sent somewhere else to have exciting things done to it.

Context: this style is applied by hand as authors build up their documents. As well as formatting the text appropriately, it identifies text that must later be pulled out into another summary document. This is currently an Excel worksheet but, dependent on requirements, could also be another Word document.

I note with interest this question and its answer: [Find paragraphs by style in word 2010 using interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443342/find-paragraphs-by-style-in-word-2010-using-interop)

I (think I) need to do this in VBA rather than C#, however, as I would like to add it to my Normal.dotm default template, for easy distribution to my team.

I think the question I am *really* asking is "what is the most efficient way to walk through a document and check the style applied to each word, performing an action on that word if required?"

The target documents can be quite large - >400 pages - and so efficiency may well be a thing.

Things I can't do, for business reasons:

1. Change to another product or format for the documents involved
2. Change to a newer version of Word
3. Use a language or tool that doesn't come as default with Word

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that Word's built-in Find functionality can find styles (and other formatting), without needing to search any text? Press Ctrl+H, click on the "Find" tab, click the "More" button, choose "Style" and select the style you want to find. Use the "Find next" button to test finding the style. Once you feel comfortable with this, record finding the style in a macro to get the basic code. Click the [edit] link below your question to add the code to it. (Otherwise, your question falls under the "too broad" category - you need to show research on your part.)

Comment: Once you have the core code, you need to specify *where* you want this information (text fromatted with the style) to be saved. *You* have to tell *us*, otherwise your question falls under "Primarily opinion-based". Please be specific, "currently an Excel worksheet" does not provide enough information.

Comment: Not sure why I need to tell you _where_ this information needs to go. It's out of scope; I'm not asking about handling the information once it's been found.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `.Find` method and specify the style with `.Style`.
Example:

```
Sub ScratchMacro()
'A basic Word macro coded by Greg Maxey
Dim oRng As Word.Range
Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
  With oRng.Find
    .Style = "Heading 1" 'Replace this with name of your style
    While .Execute
      ActiveDocument.Range.InsertAfter vbCr & oRng
      ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Style = "Normal"
      oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Wend
  End With
End Sub
```

Source: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/23001-creating-list-all-text-specific-style.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems to lock in an infinite loop when crawling all styles.

Working a different approach to select all styles, add to a selection the apply the style, however the character styles and paragraphs styles are breaking the formatting... I think I found a workaround ... may be redundant?

```
Sub STYLE_reset_overrides_to_style()
''override independent text overrides with style formatting.
''Selection.ClearCharacterStyle  unfortunately ALSO clears character styles along with independent formatting.
''Maybe look for all non-paragraph styles to add to selection adn apply char styles?
' https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/47165-macro-select-headings-all-styles.html
'Adapted to select ranges and pleace styles.
Dim oParas As Paragraph     ''selected paragraphs
Dim oChar As Characters     ''selection characters???<-----break and debug if char styles need to eb separate...
Dim oStyle As Style         ''styles to find/replace

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ActiveDocument.DeleteAllEditableRanges wdEditorEveryone

    ''For my case- we want to clear all direct formatting and rely 100% on styles...
    ''Could search for special formatting and create styles before clearing as well...
    Selection.WholeStory                        ''Select everything
    Selection.ClearCharacterDirectFormatting    ''clear direct formatting. Styles intact.
    
    
    For Each oStyle In ActiveDocument.Styles    ''Cycle through styles to match....

        If oStyle.InUse And oStyle.Description Like "*indent:*" Then
            For Each oParas In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
              If oParas.Style = oStyle Then     ''If styles match then add to collection
                oParas.Range.Editors.Add wdEditorEveryone   ''add to editable collection
              End If
            Next
        
            ActiveDocument.SelectAllEditableRanges wdEditorEveryone ''Select all applicable paragraphs
                
            If Not Selection Is Nothing Then    ''if there is something selected...    
            
                ''Find Replace active selection of selected - quick way to apply corresponding styles
                Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
                Selection.Find.Style = oStyle
                Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
                Selection.Find.Replacement.Style = oStyle
                
                With Selection.Find
                    .Text = ""
                    .Replacement.Text = ""
                    .Forward = True
                    .Wrap = wdFindContinue      ''Replace everything everywhere
                    .Format = True
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .MatchWholeWord = False
                    .MatchWildcards = False
                    .MatchSoundsLike = False
                    .MatchAllWordForms = False
                End With
                
                Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll    'Execute find/replace styles
                
                ActiveDocument.DeleteAllEditableRanges wdEditorEveryone ''delete selection collection
            End If
        End If
    Next oStyle
    
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```