# Word interop find used styles in document

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm trying to find all the styles that are used in a document in Word.
I can iterate over every style in an document and check for the `InUse` property but reading this documentation:

> This property doesn't necessarily indicate whether the style is currently applied to any text in the document. For instance, if text that's been formatted with a style is deleted, the InUse property of the style remains True. For built-in styles that have never been used in the document, this property returns False.

from Microsoft it shows me too many styles. Is there a fast way to retrieve these styles?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find paragraphs by style in word 2010 using interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443342/find-paragraphs-by-style-in-word-2010-using-interop)

Comment: No particularly fast way, no... To get a completely accurate list you'd need to loop every character in the document. Faster would probably be to parse the WordOpenXML...

Comment: @MrJF I'm not searching for paragraphs by style i'm looking for the styles that are used in a document.

Comment: @CindyMeister how would you do it with OpenXml I see the list of styles but these are the same(too much) as I get with the interop?

Comment: I can now parse all used styles from the wordopenxml propertie but now I need them to match with the interop styles. The names of styles mismatch.
I've also noticied that the ID's used for styles in WordOpenXML are language dependent

Comment: After you get the style IDs from the main document body you need to *look them up* in the styles.xml (Styles Part). There you should get a match to the "interop styles" (the style names visible in the UI). The *visible* style names are language-dependent for Word's built-in styles, only. And for these you should get a non-language-dependent "ID" from the Styles part.

Comment: Thanks but they are not completly the same example I got 'heading 1' in openxml and in interop I got Heading 1. This is only a minor difference but maybe there are more of these